# DbLookUpComboBox doesn't allows select item

Tags: delphi, combobox, datasource

I've used the component DbLookUpComboBox to display a list of customers, and It's working okay, the problem is, when i select one of the values, it just ignores my selection and keep leaving a blank value at component.

This is my List Source:

```
DECLARE @ID_USR INT
DECLARE @FOUND BIT

SET @ID_USR = :ID_USUARIO
SET @FOUND = 0

SELECT @FOUND = 1
FROM
    DBUSUARIO U
    INNER JOIN DBUSUARIO_GRUPO UG ON U.ID_GRUPO = UG.ID_GRUPO
    INNER JOIN dbCONTROLE_REGIAO_GRUPO_USUARIO CRGU ON U.ID_GRUPO = CRGU.ID_GRUPO
    INNER JOIN dbCLIENTE_REGIAO CR ON CRGU.ID_REGIAO = CR.ID_REGIAO
    INNER JOIN DBCLIENTE C ON CR.ID_CLIENTE = C.ID_CLIENTE
WHERE
    U.ID_USUARIO = @ID_USR

IF(@FOUND = 1)
    SELECT C.FANTASIA, C.ID_CLIENTE
    FROM
        DBUSUARIO U
        INNER JOIN DBUSUARIO_GRUPO UG ON U.ID_GRUPO = UG.ID_GRUPO
        INNER JOIN dbCONTROLE_REGIAO_GRUPO_USUARIO CRGU ON U.ID_GRUPO = CRGU.ID_GRUPO
        INNER JOIN dbCLIENTE_REGIAO CR ON CRGU.ID_REGIAO = CR.ID_REGIAO
        INNER JOIN DBCLIENTE C ON CR.ID_CLIENTE = C.ID_CLIENTE
    WHERE
        U.ID_USUARIO = @ID_USR
    GROUP BY
        C.FANTASIA, C.ID_CLIENTE
    ORDER BY
        C.FANTASIA

ELSE
    SELECT 
        C.FANTASIA, C.ID_CLIENTE FROM DBCLIENTE C
    GROUP BY
        C.FANTASIA, C.ID_CLIENTE
    ORDER BY
        C.FANTASIA
```

And this is my Data Source:

```
DECLARE @FOUND BIT
DECLARE @REFERENCIA VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @IDUSR INT
DECLARE @IDPAIS INT
DECLARE @IDESTADO INT
DECLARE @IDCIDADE INT
DECLARE @TIPO INT


SET @REFERENCIA = :REFERENCIA
SET @IDUSR = :ID_USUARIO
SET @IDPAIS = - :ID_PAIS
SET @IDESTADO = :ID_ESTADO
SET @IDCIDADE = :ID_CIDADE
SET @TIPO = :TIPO

SET @FOUND = 0

SELECT @FOUND = 1
FROM
    DBUSUARIO U
    INNER JOIN DBUSUARIO_GRUPO UG ON U.ID_GRUPO = UG.ID_GRUPO
    INNER JOIN dbCONTROLE_REGIAO_GRUPO_USUARIO CRGU ON U.ID_GRUPO = CRGU.ID_GRUPO
    INNER JOIN dbCLIENTE_REGIAO CR ON CRGU.ID_REGIAO = CR.ID_REGIAO
    INNER JOIN DBCLIENTE C ON CR.ID_CLIENTE = C.ID_CLIENTE
WHERE U.ID_USUARIO = @IDUSR

IF(@FOUND = 1)

     SELECT DISTINCT
        ISNULL(DBPONTO_TIPO.ICONE, 'APISUL.CGM') ICONE,
        DBPONTO.ID_PONTO, DBPONTO.NOME, DBPAIS.DESCRICAO PAIS,
        DBESTADO.DESCRICAO ESTADO, DBCIDADE.DESCRICAO CIDADE,
        DBPONTO.FONE1, DBPONTO.FONE2, DBPONTO.LATITUDE,
        DBPONTO.LONGITUDE, DBPONTO.RAIO, DBPONTO.ENDERECO,
        DBPONTO.BAIRRO, DBPONTO.CEP, DBPONTO.STATUS, DBPONTO.ID_CLIENTE, 
        DBPONTO.ID_TIPO, DBPONTO.HOMOLOGADO, DBPONTO.FLAG, 
        DBPONTO.CLASSIFICACAO, DBPONTO.ID_CIDADE, DBPONTO.PONTO_GERAL,
        DBESTADO.ID_ESTADO, DBPAIS.ID_PAIS, DBPONTO.PERIMETRO,
        DS_TIPO_PONTO = CASE WHEN DBPONTO.PERIMETRO = 'P'  THEN 'PERIMETRO' ELSE 'PONTO' END,
        ID_PONTO_CLASSIFICACAO, C.FANTASIA/*, DBPONTO.ID_CLIENTE, DBPONTO.PONTO_GERAL*/
    FROM

        DBUSUARIO U
        INNER JOIN DBUSUARIO_GRUPO UG ON U.ID_GRUPO = UG.ID_GRUPO
        INNER JOIN dbCONTROLE_REGIAO_GRUPO_USUARIO CRGU ON U.ID_GRUPO = CRGU.ID_GRUPO
        INNER JOIN dbCLIENTE_REGIAO CR ON CRGU.ID_REGIAO = CR.ID_REGIAO
        INNER JOIN DBCLIENTE C ON CR.ID_CLIENTE = C.ID_CLIENTE

        LEFT JOIN DBPONTO ON (C.ID_CLIENTE = DBPONTO.ID_CLIENTE)
        LEFT JOIN DBPONTO_TIPO ON(DBPONTO.ID_TIPO = DBPONTO_TIPO.ID_TIPO)
        LEFT JOIN DBCIDADE ON(DBCIDADE.ID_CIDADE = DBPONTO.ID_CIDADE)
        LEFT JOIN DBESTADO ON(DBESTADO.ID_ESTADO = DBCIDADE.ID_ESTADO)
        LEFT JOIN DBPAIS ON(DBPAIS.ID_PAIS = DBESTADO.ID_PAIS)

    WHERE 
        (DBPONTO.NOME LIKE @REFERENCIA) 
        AND (DBPONTO.ID_TIPO > 0) 
        AND (DBPONTO.CLASSIFICACAO = 1) 
        AND (DBPAIS.ID_PAIS = @IDPAIS OR @IDPAIS = -1) 
        AND (DBESTADO.ID_ESTADO = @IDESTADO OR @IDESTADO = -1) 
        AND (DBCIDADE.ID_CIDADE = @IDCIDADE OR @IDCIDADE = -1) 
        AND (DBPONTO.ID_TIPO = @TIPO OR @TIPO = -1)
        AND (ID_USUARIO = @IDUSR OR DBPONTO.PONTO_GERAL = 1)

    UNION

    SELECT
        ISNULL(DBPONTO_TIPO.ICONE, 'APISUL.CGM') ICONE,
        DBPONTO.ID_PONTO, DBPONTO.NOME, DBPAIS.DESCRICAO PAIS,
        DBESTADO.DESCRICAO ESTADO, DBCIDADE.DESCRICAO CIDADE,
        DBPONTO.FONE1, DBPONTO.FONE2, DBPONTO.LATITUDE,
        DBPONTO.LONGITUDE, DBPONTO.RAIO, DBPONTO.ENDERECO,
        DBPONTO.BAIRRO, DBPONTO.CEP, DBPONTO.STATUS, DBPONTO.ID_CLIENTE, 
        DBPONTO.ID_TIPO, DBPONTO.HOMOLOGADO, DBPONTO.FLAG, 
        DBPONTO.CLASSIFICACAO, DBPONTO.ID_CIDADE, DBPONTO.PONTO_GERAL,
        DBESTADO.ID_ESTADO, DBPAIS.ID_PAIS, DBPONTO.PERIMETRO,
        DS_TIPO_PONTO = CASE WHEN DBPONTO.PERIMETRO = 'P'  THEN 'PERIMETRO' ELSE 'PONTO' END,
        ID_PONTO_CLASSIFICACAO, C.FANTASIA

    FROM DBPONTO
        LEFT JOIN DBPONTO_TIPO ON(DBPONTO.ID_TIPO = DBPONTO_TIPO.ID_TIPO)
        LEFT JOIN DBCIDADE ON(DBCIDADE.ID_CIDADE = DBPONTO.ID_CIDADE)
        LEFT JOIN DBESTADO ON(DBESTADO.ID_ESTADO = DBCIDADE.ID_ESTADO)
        LEFT JOIN DBPAIS ON(DBPAIS.ID_PAIS = DBESTADO.ID_PAIS)
        LEFT JOIN DBCLIENTE C ON (DBPONTO.ID_CLIENTE = C.ID_CLIENTE)

    WHERE PONTO_GERAL = 1

    ORDER BY DBPONTO.NOME


ELSE
    SELECT 
        ISNULL(DBPONTO_TIPO.ICONE, 'APISUL.CGM') ICONE,
        DBPONTO.ID_PONTO, DBPONTO.NOME, DBPAIS.DESCRICAO PAIS,
        DBESTADO.DESCRICAO ESTADO, DBCIDADE.DESCRICAO CIDADE,
        DBPONTO.FONE1, DBPONTO.FONE2, DBPONTO.LATITUDE,
        DBPONTO.LONGITUDE, DBPONTO.RAIO, DBPONTO.ENDERECO,
        DBPONTO.BAIRRO, DBPONTO.CEP, DBPONTO.STATUS, DBPONTO.ID_CLIENTE, 
        DBPONTO.ID_TIPO, DBPONTO.HOMOLOGADO, DBPONTO.FLAG, 
        DBPONTO.CLASSIFICACAO, DBPONTO.ID_CIDADE, DBPONTO.PONTO_GERAL,
        DBESTADO.ID_ESTADO, DBPAIS.ID_PAIS, DBPONTO.PERIMETRO,
        DS_TIPO_PONTO = CASE WHEN DBPONTO.PERIMETRO = 'P'  THEN 'PERIMETRO' ELSE 'PONTO' END,
       ID_PONTO_CLASSIFICACAO, DBCLIENTE.FANTASIA
    FROM

        DBPONTO
        LEFT JOIN DBCLIENTE ON (DBPONTO.ID_CLIENTE = DBCLIENTE.ID_CLIENTE)
        LEFT JOIN DBPONTO_TIPO ON(DBPONTO.ID_TIPO = DBPONTO_TIPO.ID_TIPO)
        LEFT JOIN DBCIDADE ON(DBCIDADE.ID_CIDADE = DBPONTO.ID_CIDADE)
        LEFT JOIN DBESTADO ON(DBESTADO.ID_ESTADO = DBCIDADE.ID_ESTADO)
        LEFT JOIN DBPAIS ON(DBPAIS.ID_PAIS = DBESTADO.ID_PAIS)
    WHERE 
        ((DBPONTO.NOME LIKE @REFERENCIA) 
        AND (DBPONTO.ID_TIPO > 0) 
        AND (DBPONTO.CLASSIFICACAO = 1) 
        AND (DBPAIS.ID_PAIS = @IDPAIS OR @IDPAIS = -1) 
        AND (DBESTADO.ID_ESTADO = @IDESTADO OR @IDESTADO = -1)
        AND (DBCIDADE.ID_CIDADE = @IDCIDADE OR @IDCIDADE = -1) 
        AND (DBPONTO.ID_TIPO = @TIPO OR @TIPO = -1))


    UNION

    SELECT
        ISNULL(DBPONTO_TIPO.ICONE, 'APISUL.CGM') ICONE,
        DBPONTO.ID_PONTO, DBPONTO.NOME, DBPAIS.DESCRICAO PAIS,
        DBESTADO.DESCRICAO ESTADO, DBCIDADE.DESCRICAO CIDADE,
        DBPONTO.FONE1, DBPONTO.FONE2, DBPONTO.LATITUDE,
        DBPONTO.LONGITUDE, DBPONTO.RAIO, DBPONTO.ENDERECO,
        DBPONTO.BAIRRO, DBPONTO.CEP, DBPONTO.STATUS, DBPONTO.ID_CLIENTE, 
        DBPONTO.ID_TIPO, DBPONTO.HOMOLOGADO, DBPONTO.FLAG, 
        DBPONTO.CLASSIFICACAO, DBPONTO.ID_CIDADE, DBPONTO.PONTO_GERAL,
        DBESTADO.ID_ESTADO, DBPAIS.ID_PAIS, DBPONTO.PERIMETRO,
        DS_TIPO_PONTO = CASE WHEN DBPONTO.PERIMETRO = 'P'  THEN 'PERIMETRO' ELSE 'PONTO' END,
        ID_PONTO_CLASSIFICACAO, C.FANTASIA

    FROM DBPONTO
        LEFT JOIN DBPONTO_TIPO ON(DBPONTO.ID_TIPO = DBPONTO_TIPO.ID_TIPO)
        LEFT JOIN DBCIDADE ON(DBCIDADE.ID_CIDADE = DBPONTO.ID_CIDADE)
        LEFT JOIN DBESTADO ON(DBESTADO.ID_ESTADO = DBCIDADE.ID_ESTADO)
        LEFT JOIN DBPAIS ON(DBPAIS.ID_PAIS = DBESTADO.ID_PAIS)
        LEFT JOIN DBCLIENTE C ON (DBPONTO.ID_CLIENTE = C.ID_CLIENTE)

    WHERE PONTO_GERAL = 1

    ORDER BY DBPONTO.NOME
```

**Data Field: ID_CLIENTE**

**Key Field: ID_CLIENTE**

**List Field: FANTASIA**

I've got an exception that said: "Trying to modify read-only field"

Answer (score 0):

For the DBLookupComboBox to assign a value to the destination datasource, the datasource needs to be updateable. The datasource query looks kind of complex to me and there are  UNIONS in it. Because of this, a matching insert/update statement cannot be calculated automatically and Delphi considers the datasource and its fields readonly. Thus, the value cannot be modified when you change it using the combobox and you get the error.

I think you should either simplify the datasource query to use maximum a single simple table as a source, or manually provide matching insert and update statements for the query.

Comment: I've tried to take out the union, but I got the same error, any idea?

Comment: No, sorry, other than to simplify it further. I think that Delphi's SQL parser really is not a lot smarter than recognizing simple "SELECT a, b, c FROM t" type statements. What DB components are you using, ADO, BDE, dbExpress, other?  You could try to use other database components that allow you to set the Insert / Update / Delete statements yourself instead of relying on Delphi to parse it for you.

Comment: I was forgetting an important attribute, my field was setted as readonly :/ Then the problem was not the complex query.

But thankyou for try help! =)